# PHP ssh2_exec, executing multiple commands at once

Tags: php, bash, libssh2

I'm using ssh2_exec to execute a few commands from PHP on my CentOS servers, and I have used it many times, but today, when I tried making it do 4 or 5 commands at once with &&, it did not work. Here is the code below:

```
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'cp -rf /home/shared/Tekkit_Server_3.1.2.zip /home/servers2/'.$mUsername.' && unzip /home/servers2/'.$mUsername.'/Tekkit_Server_3.1.2.zip && rm -rf /home/servers2/'.$mUsername.'/mods/mod_NetherOres.jar && mv -f /home/servers2/'.$mUsername.'/Tekkit.jar /home/servers2/'.$mUsername.'/craftbukkit.jar'))) {
    echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
}
```

It copy's the ZIP over to the right directory, but then does nothing from there, any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I tried doing just:

```
 if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'unzip /home/servers2/'.$mUsername.'/Tekkit_Server_3.1.2.zip'))){
                        echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
 }
```

and it returned: fail: unable to execute command

Other commands work fine, and when I run the command in the terminal it works fine.

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php#59324

Comment: Didn't seem to work using that method. I even just now tried separating them into separate commands with a sleep(5); in between each and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you have it output the results to a log on the target machine and then go look to see where it failed?

Comment: It's deffinatly failing with the unzip, but no error, for now I have just unzip the file on the server and I am copying that over, but only a temp fix I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your example and it looks like it works if you supply `-d` option to `unzip` command and specify the directory where the file should be unpacked:

```
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'unzip /home/servers2/'.$mUsername.'/Tekkit_Server_3.1.2.zip -d /home/servers2/'.$mUsername))){
    echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
}
```